# $\sqrt{n+\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt[3]{n+\cdots \cdots \cdots }}}$ is a natural number, is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The number of natural number $n\leq 50$ such that
>
> $\displaystyle \sqrt{n+\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt[3]{n+\cdots \cdots \cdots }}}$ is a natural number, is

Try: Let $\displaystyle x=\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt[3]{n+\cdots \cdots \cdots }}$

So $\displaystyle x=\sqrt[3]{n+x}\Rightarrow x^3=n+x\Rightarrow x^3-x-n=0$

could some help me how to solve it, Thanks

Comment: @Winther - you shouldn't edit based on assumptions. How do you know that was a typo, and the SQUARE root wasn't actually meant as such?

Comment: @Winther - No it isn't. If I wanted to solve the problem, with an outer SQUARE root, I would start exactly the same way as the OP did. Clearly if the expression (with a square root at the outer-most) is a natural number, then $x$ is also a natural number.

Comment: I have edited my post , gays please see that. thanks

Comment: @Winther May be, may be not. Perhaps the OP has mixed it up in their own notes whether the outermost root is a square root or a cube root. There is no way for us to tell with _certainty_ what the _original_ problem that the OP is supposed to solve is. Which is why I agree with mathguy that it is better to ask and wait rather than edit directly. Besides, more than once have I been in the middle of a substantial edit of my own questions and answers when someone decides to correct a minor typo, making me lose all my progress. That's somewhat annoying.

Comment: I'm still wandering: the outmost root is cubic or square? Every answer that doesn't come from the OP is speculation

Comment: **CAN EVERYBODY PLEASE STOP DEFACING THE OP'S POST? THE OP HIMSELF CHANGED THIS BACK TO AN OUTER SQUARE ROOT. STOP CHANGING THAT.**

Comment: So it's an outer square root but the x indeed begins with a cube root? To: @mathguy, op, et al

Answer (score 3):

$n = 0$ would fit. Now let's assume $n > 0$.

I think you are on the right track. If the given expression, call it $y$, is a natural number, then $x = y^2 - n$ must also be an integer - and it is strictly positive, so it must be a natural number.

Then from $x^3-x-n = 0$ and $x$ being an integer, we conclude that $x$ must be a divisor of $n$, and in particular $x \le n$.

Since $n \le 50$, we get $x^3 = x + n \le 100$, which means $x \le 4$. Try $x = 1, 2, 3, 4$, compute the respective $n$, and see if $y$ is still an integer.

Comment: Good observations!

Answer (score 2):

If zero is a natural number, then $n=0$

Otherwise, [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-x-n%3D0,%20x%20is%20an%20integer) gives integer solutions of $x$ for $n=6$ and $n=24$

$$x^3-x-24=0 \implies x = 3$$

$$x^3-x-6=0 \implies x = 2$$

There's probably some algebra or number theory way to go about ensuring that $x$ is an integer if $n$ is an integer.

Update: it's the [rational root theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2907568).

Answer (score 2):

By the rational root theorem, a solution of $$x^3-x-n=0$$ must be a divisor of $-n.$  Since $n\leq50$ such a solution can't be very large. By definition of $x$ we have $x\geq0$.  If $x=4,$ then $x^3 =64$ and there's already no hope.  So $x$ must be one of $0, 1, 2, 3.$

$$\begin{align}
x&=0\implies n=0\\
x&=1\implies n=0\\
x&=2\implies n=6\\
x&=3\implies n=24
\end{align}$$

Now you have to test these combinations of $n$ and $x$ to see $n+x$ is a perfect square.  The only ones that work are the ones where $n=0$ and obviously $x=1$ is wrong in that case.  So we are left with $n=0,$ which isn't very interesting.

I suspect that there really is supposed to be a cube root on the outside, and the answer is $n=24, x=3.$

Answer (score 1):

Using the [formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula) for finding the roots of the general cubic equation we obtain the numerical criterion:
$$
\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt[3]{n+}\ldots}}}\in \mathbb{N} \Longleftrightarrow
 \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{n}{2}+\sqrt{\dfrac{n^2}{4}-\dfrac{1}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{n}{2}-\sqrt{\dfrac{n^2}{4}-\dfrac{1}{27}}}
\in \mathbb{N}
$$

Let  the cubic equation $a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d = 0$ with $a \ne 0$. In this case we have 
$
a=1\qquad b=0 \qquad c=-1 \quad \mbox{ and } \quad d=-n
$
and 
$
1\cdot x^3-0\cdot x^2-1\cdot x-n=0. Let
$

$Q = \dfrac {3 a c - b^2} {9 a^2}=-\dfrac{1}{3}$

$R = \dfrac {9 a b c - 27 a^2 d - 2 b^3} {54 a^3}=\dfrac{n}{2}$

$S = \sqrt [3] {R + \sqrt{Q^3 + R^2}}=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{n}{2}+\sqrt{\dfrac{n^2}{4}-\dfrac{1}{27}}}$

$T = \sqrt [3] {R - \sqrt{Q^3 + R^2}}=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{n}{2}-\sqrt{\dfrac{n^2}{4}-\dfrac{1}{27}}}$

If  $D = Q^3 + R^2\geq 0 $ ( In this case $D=\dfrac{n^2}{4}-\dfrac{1}{27} >0$ ) then the cubic equation has solutions:

$x_1 = S + T - \dfrac b {3 a}= \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{n}{2}+\sqrt{\dfrac{n^2}{4}-\dfrac{1}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{n}{2}-\sqrt{\dfrac{n^2}{4}-\dfrac{1}{27}}}$

$x_2 = - \dfrac {S + T} 2 - \dfrac b {3 a} + \dfrac {i \sqrt 3} 2 \left({S - T}\right)$

$x_3 = - \dfrac {S + T} 2 - \dfrac b {3 a} - \dfrac {i \sqrt 3} 2 \left({S - T}\right)$

If  $D = Q^3 + R^2<0 $ then the cubic equation has solutions:

$x_1 = 2 \sqrt {-Q} \cos \left({\dfrac \theta 3}\right) - \dfrac b {3 a}$

$x_2 = 2 \sqrt {-Q} \cos \left({\dfrac \theta 3 + \dfrac {2 \pi} 3}\right) - \dfrac b {3 a}$

$x_3 = 2 \sqrt {-Q} \cos \left({\dfrac \theta 3 + \dfrac {4 \pi} 3}\right) - \dfrac b {3 a}$

where $\cos(\theta)=\frac{R}{\sqrt{-Q^3}}$

Comment: So, what is/are the $n$'s, MathOverview?

Answer (score 1):

With $$\displaystyle \sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt[3]{n+\cdots \cdots \cdots }}}$$ We get $$x^3-x-n=0$$

Thus $$n=x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$$

Therefore for any natural number $x>1$ we have a natural number $n$ satisfying $$n=x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$$

For example with $x=5$ we get $n=120$ and for $x=10$ we get $n=990.$

Another way of saying that is for any three natural numbers, we can have their product as $n$ and the middle of the three natural numbers to be $x$